# Conditions on $p, f$ to be an expectation operator

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

A person waiting in line has a waiting time $\tau$. Define $$E[H(\tau)] = \rho H(0) + \int_{0}^{\infty} H(t) f(t) dt \tag{*},$$
for all functions $H$ for which $(*)$ is defined. I wish to find the conditions on $\rho$ and $f$ for which this formula is an expectation on the sample space $\Omega_{\tau}$, and to give an interpretation of this formula. There are three axioms which I must verify:

(1) $E(c_1 X_1 + c_2X_2) = c_1E(X_1) + c_2E(X_2)$.

- By the linearity of the integral, this property immediately follows.
- $E[\sum_{i=1}^{2} c_i X_i] = \sum_{i=1}^{2} c_i(\rho X_i(0) + \int_{0}^{\infty} X_i(t) f(t) dt$)

(2) $E(1) = 1$

- $E(1) = \rho + \int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) dt = 1$

(3) $X \geq 0 \Rightarrow E(X) \geq 0.$

- $E(X) = \rho X(0) + \int_{0}^{\infty} X(t)f(t) dt \geq 0$

I do not see what information about $\rho, f$ I can extract from properties $(2)$ and $(3)$, or how to give a physical interpretation of the formula $(*)$.

Comment: This almost looks like a zero-inflated model: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-inflated_model, where $\rho=P(\tau=0)$ (i.e., empty-queue probability) and $f(t)$ is the distribution over the remaining $1-\rho$ probability that waiting time is non-zero. In that case, $\int_0^{\infty}f(t)dt = 1-\rho$ and $\rho \in [0,1]$